# Windows 11 - Windows Update keeps installing old Radeon Vega 8 drivers

Tags: windows-update, windows-11, display-driver

I've got a Ryzen 5 2500U system with integrated Radeon Vega 8. When I install the latest AMD Adrenalin drivers for the GPU, Windows Update keeps installing a nearly 3 year old version on top of the Adrenalin driver. What can I do?

Comment: See if the manufacturer of the computer has the correct driver on their site.

Comment: It only has an older driver for Win 10.

Comment: Try that driver and see if it works.  Also (and perhaps before trying the drive), open Device Manager, open Display, right click on the driver and see if you can update it that way.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I used wushowhide (download it from majorgeeks.com). It has actually hidden the update containing an old AMD display driver.

wushowhide is the Microsoft app to hide unwanted updates. I've hidden the display driver and now Windows Update shows that there are no updates available (because I've already installed all the updates, except the old display driver), so I can keep the latest Adrenalin driver.

Steps:

1. Download the driver you want to install and wushowhide.
2. Disconnect from the Internet
3. Install the driver you've just downloaded
4. Restart
5. Connect to the Internet (don't search for updates manually) and use wushowhide to search and hide the unwanted update